# Constant specific method using Enums OR Refection ? Need to invoke methods based on string

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) sent to the DAO (Data Access Object).

DTO has an identifier string.

Based on this string (or rather the DTO), I want to invoke specific methods in the DAO.

These methods make database calls.

I have found two options to do this: 
1. Constant specific method implementation using Enum
2. Invoke the method based on reflection ( in which case the DTO will carry the name of the method that needs to be invoked.)

I want to know which is a better option. Are there any other alternatives ? Is it okay to have database calls within the Enum.

The programming language used is Java.

Answer (score 1):

I would not put database calls within your Enum.  Instead, provide a method on your DAO that accepts the DTO, and then let that method call other methods within the DAO based on the string on the DTO.  You could use a switch statement on the Enum, and make this very efficient.  (Alternatively, put this implementation in a separate "adapter" class, since it could be argued that this code doesn't strictly belong in the DAO, either.)

I would also avoid reflection, mainly due to additional complexities - including in debugging and troubleshooting, as well as potential security concerns.  (What if the String contained a method name that you didn't want called?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate on two things: 1) " let that method call other methods within the DAO based on the string on the DTO" How would you achieve this ? 2) I am interested in knowing why you think its not a good idea to put database calls in Enums.

Comment: +1 for Buc's answer for an example on how to achieve dynamically calling the methods in the DAO.  For the other part, while there is nothing to technically believe this - and is debatable, at least my viewpoint is that Enums should be used as identifiers - and not contain performing actions.  (There are certainly situations where it is appropriate to have additional methods within Enums, but these are usually used for metadata purposes for each value on the Enum itself.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I am almost convinced to go with Buc's suggestion.

Comment: @Vinay - I would use a hybrid approach.  Use an Enum as your identifier, and then use an `EnumMap` to store your actions.  It will be more efficient - as well as guaranteeing that actions can't exist without a matching Enum, which could help to prevent typos, etc.

Comment: If you are able to modify the DTOs to include `enum`s instead of strings as identifier, than ziesemer's `EnumMap` solution will truly be more efficient.

Comment: I was thinking of having one static final string in my DTO each. This sounds good. I will try to implement it. The documentation says"All of the keys in an enum map must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the map is created". So my DTO will have to reference this enum, right ? Where would be a good place to declare this enum ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a map that maps the strings to method calls:

```
class YourDAO {

    private interface Action {
        public void perform();
    }

    private Map<String, Action> actions;

    public YourDAO() {
        actions.add("String1", new Action() {
            public void perform() {
                daoMethod1();
            }
        }
        actions.add("String2", new Action() {
            public void perform() {
                daoMethod2();
            }
        }
    }

    public void daoMethod1() {
        ...
    }

    public void daoMethod2() {
        ...
    }

    public void doSomethingWithDTO(YourDTO dto) {
        actions.get(dto.getIdentifier()).perform();
    }

}
```

You can even adapt this idea to perform specific actions on different DTO types if you
change the key type of the map to `Class<?>` and instead of `dto.getIdentifier()` use `dto.getClass()`.

Comment: This seems like a good idea to me. Thank you very much for your quick reply. Would be interesting to see other answers, advantages and disadvantages of each option. I am not a big fan of reflection and I try to avoid it unless absolutely necessary.